# Fluid Type with Zoom

Tags: css, fluid-layout, typography

My requirements are:

1. From 1280 to 1920, font size should be fluid 14px to 22px
2. Users should be able to zoom as normal

I haven't found a solution that actually does both. Yes I've seen CSS Tricks simplified fluid, using `vw` of any kind renders zoom ineffective.

- `clamp(0.875em, 1.146vw, 1.375em)` - doesn't scale a the same rate as regular zoom, it's like 5% instead of 50%.
- `clamp(0.875em, 1.4vw - 0.3em, 1.375em)` - runs into the `min` and `max` but shrinks on zoom.
- `calc(0.875em + 8 * (100vw - 1280) / 640)` - doesn't zoom.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS calculations have limitations e.g. multiplication require one of the numbers to be unitless [ref](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-calc-in-css/#multiplication-requires-one-of-the-numbers-to-be-unitless). So the formula which we were targeting can't be achieved in CSS:

```css
clamp(14px, calc(1.09375vw + (0.05208vw * (100vw - 1280px) / 640)), 22px)
```

To cover all requirements we need handle this using JavaScript:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.scale');

function updateFontSize() {
  let size = 14;
  let vpWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let zoom = ((window.outerWidth) / window.innerWidth);

  if (vpWidth >= 1920) {
    size = 22;
  } else if (vpWidth <= 1280) {
    size = 14;
  } else {
    //calculate
    size = 14 + (vpWidth - 1280) * 8 / 640;
  }
  //apply zoom
  size *= zoom;

  element.style.setProperty('--font-size', size + 'px');

  document.getElementById('stats').innerText = 'Viewport Width: ' + vpWidth + 'px  \nZoom: ' + (zoom.toFixed(2) * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';
}


window.addEventListener('resize', () => updateFontSize());
updateFontSize();
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.f14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.f22 {
  font-size: 1.376rem;
}

.scale {
  --font-size: 14px;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1980px) {
  body {
    background-color: wheat;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=stats></div>
<hr><br>
<p class=f14>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.| 14px</p>
<p class=scale>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.| scaling</p>
<p class=f22>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.| 22px</p>
```

Because StackOverflow puts output in iframe you won't see actual result running the snippet here. Switch to `Full Page` or run the code in separate local HTML file.

The way I found zoom level in above code requires code not placed in iframe. Finding zoom level of browser is not an easy task. See [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365777/15273968) for more info. 

I didn't get the perceived vs required font size at 150% zoom. Also, let us know what should happen if user zooms out to 50%.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not meet either requirement.

At 1920, the font size is 21.0521, not 22.

Zoomed in to 150%, font size is clamped at 14. the viewport scales down when zooming. 
14 * 150% = 21px percieved zoom
22 * 150% = 33px required zoom

Comment: I think pure CSS solution won't be possible we need to use JavaScript. Can you give use cases for font size for 1) 1280 wide viewport zoomed to 150% and 2) 1920 wide viewport zoomed to 150%. What should happen on zoom out to 50%?

Comment: 1280 viewport = 14px + zoom 150% = 21px
1920 viewport = 22px + zoom 150% = 33px
1280 viewport = 14px - zoom 50% = 7px
1920 viewport = 22px - zoom 50% = 11px

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to achieve it with CSS only, but even with JavaScript it's quite a straightforward solution. Please let me know if I misunderstood something from the requirements.

### Solution

I'm resetting the `--fluid-size` CSS variable at `load` & `resize` events by running the `resetFluidSize` function (notice this process will hurt the performance as it triggers **reflows** every time it runs, I'm not doing any optimization here in order to keep it simple).

Then I used the `outerWidth` to prevent the zoom level (which affects the `innerWidth`) from messing up the proper scale so no matter the page zoom, the computed style will be the desired one.

After doing the math, I update the CSS variable with `document.body.style.setProperty`.

### Note

In order to see the right values, run the code snippet *Full page*.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  resetFluidSize();
  window.addEventListener('resize', resetFluidSize);
});

const
  a = 14,
  b = 22;

function resetFluidSize() {
  const
    factor = (window.outerWidth - 1280) / 640,
    lerp = a + (b - a) * factor,
    clamp = Math.max(a, Math.min(b, lerp)),
    fluidSize = `${clamp}px`;

  document.body.style.setProperty('--fluid-size', fluidSize);

  /* Just to update the feedback. */
  document.getElementById('fluid-text').setAttribute('currentSize', fluidSize);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --fluid-size: 16px;
}

#fluid-text {
  font-size: var(--fluid-size);
}


/* Ignore the style below, its just for the feedback. */

p {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

p::after {
  content: attr(currentSize);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p style="font-size: 14px;" currentSize="14px">
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
  <p id="fluid-text">
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
  <p style="font-size: 22px;" currentSize="22px">
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
</body>
```

### Edit

If you want to run it locally, you can use this [index.html](https://gist.github.com/leodeslf/966c25ce4abc950219637fa46375e4b0) (a GitHub Gist).